Existence of perfect different sets as a consequence of a theorem on finite fields.
I am trying to solve the following problem:

A perfect difference set is a subset $S = \{s_0,...,s_q\} \subset \mathbb{Z}/N$ such that each non-zero element of $\mathbb{Z}/N$ occurs exactly once as the difference $s_i − s_j \space(i,j \in \{0,...,q\}, i \neq j)$ of two distinct elements of $S$. Example: $S = \{0,1,3\} \subset \mathbb{Z}/7$.
Let $k = F_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements, and let $V$ be a $3$-dimensional
vector space over $k$. Lastly, consider the following theorem proved by J. Singer:
Theorem. There exists an invertible linear transformation $f : V \to V$ which acts on the set of lines through the origin (one-dimensional subspaces) in $V$ by a cyclic permutation, so all lines occur as the successive images of any given line $L_0 = L \subset V$: denoting by $N$ the number of lines in $V$, the assignment $j \mapsto L_j = f^j(L)$ defines a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}/N$ to the set of lines in $V$. Moreover, $f$ acts in the same manner on the set of planes (two-dimensional subspaces) in $V$, with all planes arising as the successive images $P_j = f^j(P)$ of any given plane $P_0 = P \subset V$ under iterates of $f$.
(a) Assuming the theorem holds, show that $S = \{j\in \mathbb{Z}/N \mid L_j \subset P_0\}$ is a perfect difference set.
(b) Prove the theorem. Let $p(x) = x^3 - ax^2 - bx - c \in k[x]$ be a degree $3$ polynomial which has no roots in $k$, and let $K= k[x]/(p)$, i.e. the $3$-dimensional vector space of polynomials of degree $\le 2$ with coefficients in $k$, with a multiplication operation defined by taking the product of two polynomials and taking the remainder mod $p(x)$ (i.e., replacing $x^3$ by $ax^2+bx+c$, and $x^4$ by $a(ax^2+bx+c)+bx^2+cx$).
You can use, without proof, two classical facts of field theory:
$\hspace{0.5cm}$($1$) $K$ is a field (containing $k$ as a subfield);
$\hspace{0.5cm}$($2$) the multiplicative group of non-zero elements of any finite field is cyclic.
Let $\alpha$ be a generator of the multiplicative group $K^*$ of non-zero elements of $K$. Show that multiplication by $\alpha$, viewed as a linear map $f : V \to V$, has the properties of the the theorem. (Hint: take the line $L_0$ to be the subspace of constant polynomials, i.e. $k \subset K$; which powers of $\alpha$ are elements of $k$? take the plane $P_0$ to be the subspace of polynomials of degree $\le 1$, i.e. the span of $1$ and $x$).


My proof for part (a) is the following:
Since $V$ can be interpreted as a finite projective geometry it has $N = q^2 + q + 1$ lines and planes, each plane contains $q+1$ lines and each line is contained in $q+1$ planes. Let $P_0 = \{L_{d_{0}},L_{d_{1}}, \ldots, L_{d_{q}}\}$ for some integers $d_{0}, d_{1}, \ldots, d_{q} \in \mathbb{Z}/N$. The theorem implies $$P_t = \{L_{d_{0}+t},L_{d_{1}+t}, \ldots, L_{d_{q}+t}\}$$ for any $0\le t \le q^2+q$. Of all these planes, since the indices are taken mod $q^2+q+1$ and no two numbers of $d_0, d_1, \ldots, d_q$ are congruent, we can consider the planes $P_{-d_0}, P_{-d_1}, \ldots, P_{-d_q}$ and note that all of them contain $L_0$; since each pair of planes share exactly one line the rest of lines in each plane must be different, i.e. all the indices of the lines in each plane are different, so we get $(q+1)q$ different differences of the form $d_i - d_j$ as desired.

My main problem arises on part (b), I am not sure how to conclude the proof. I have tried the following:
Note that $K^*$ has $q^3-1$ elements so $\alpha^0 = \alpha^{q^3-1}$ and the first $q^3-1$ powers are all different. Note that $\alpha^0 \in L_0$ so we want to prove $L_{0} = L_{q^2+q+1} = \ldots = L_{(q-2)(q^2+q+1)}$ which would imply that $L_0 = \{\alpha^0, \alpha^{q^2+q+1}, \ldots, \alpha^{(q-2)(q^2+q+1)}\}$  and therefore, for $0 \le t \le q^2+q$ $$L_t = \alpha^tL_0 = \{\alpha^{0+t}, \alpha^{(q^2+q+1)+t}, \ldots, \alpha^{(q-2)(q^2+q+1)+t}\}$$ which proves that $f$, i.e. multiplication by $\alpha$, cycles over all lines. Similarly, let $P_0 = \{L_{d_{0}},L_{d_{1}}, \ldots, L_{d_{q}}\}$ then, for $0\le t \le q^2+q$, $$P_t = \alpha^tP_0 = \{\alpha^tL_{d_{0}},\alpha^tL_{d_{1}}, \ldots, \alpha^tL_{d_{q}}\} = \{L_{d_{0}+t},L_{d_{1}+t}, \ldots, L_{d_{q}+t}\}$$ which is the desired result (isn't it?) since there are only $q^2+q+1$ planes.

I would appreciate any help on finding the solution to part (b), specifically on proving $$L_{0} = L_{q^2+q+1} = \ldots = L_{(q-2)(q^2+q+1)}$$ and on checking if it is correct.
Keep in mind (as you will have noticed by the statement of the question and the hints given) that I found this problem while self-studying an introductory but rigorous course on abstract algebra so please avoid notation such as $PG(2,q)$ or any advanced theorem on finite projective geometry.
